# How to implement that generic function with TypeTag in Scala?

Tags: scala, types, reification

Suppose I need to write a function `convert[T]: String => Option[T]`, which works as follows:

```
 import scala.util.Try

 def toInt(s: String): Option[Int] = Try(s.toInt).toOption
 def toDouble(s: String): Option[Double] = Try(s.toDouble).toOption
 def toBoolean(s: String): Option[Boolean] = Try(s.toBoolean).toOption

 // if T is either Int, Double, or Boolean return 
 // toInt(s), toDouble(s), toBoolean(s) respectively

 def convert[T](s: String): Option[T] = ???
```

Should I use `TypeTag` to implement it ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, you should use the typeclass pattern. That way the types are resolved at compile time rather than runtime, which is much safer.

```
trait ConverterFor[T] {
  def convert(s: String): Option[T]
}
object ConverterFor {
  implicit def forInt = new ConverterFor[Int] {
    def convert(s: String) = Try(s.toInt).toOption }
  implicit def forDouble = ...
}

def convert[T](s: String)(implicit converter: ConverterFor[T]): Option[T] =
  converter.convert(s)
```

The correct `ConvertorFor` is resolved implicitly at compile time. If you try to call `convert` with a type for which there is no implicit `ConverterFor` available, it will fail to compile.

Comment: Thank you for the quick response. I guess `TypeTag[T]` is available in compile-time too.

Comment: What if I need `convert[T]` to return `None` if `T` is none of  `Int`, `Double`, `Boolean` ?

Comment: @Michael, you can define a default implicit value like this: `def convert[T](s: String)(implicit converter: ConverterFor[T] = noneConverter[T])`, where `def noneConverter[T]: ConverterFor[T] = ...` which always return `None`. This way if no implicit is available the default one will be used; if `T` is `Int`, `Double` or `Boolean`, however, the corresponding implicit will be used instead of the default one.

Comment: @VladimirMatveev Thank you very much for the suggestion ! I do not like `reflection` but I'm dealing with legacy, which uses reflection heavily. That's why I cannot get rid of it right now.

Comment: @Michael why would you want that? You know what `T` is, if you want `None` instead just use `None`. I don't understand the use case.