# How to fix this typeclass example?

Tags: scala, typeclass

This is a follow-up to my previous [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29342913/how-to-implement-that-generic-function-with-typetag-in-scala):

Suppose I create the following test `converter.scala`:

```
trait ConverterTo[T] {
  def convert(s: String): Option[T]
}

object Converters {
  implicit val toInt: ConverterTo[Int] =
    new ConverterTo[Int] { 
      def convert(s: String) = scala.util.Try(s.toInt).toOption
    }
}

class A {
  import Converters._
  def foo[T](s: String)(implicit ct: ConverterTo[T]) = ct.convert(s)
}
```

Now when I tried to call `foo` in REPL it fails to compile:

```
scala> :load converter.scala
Loading converter.scala...
defined trait ConverterTo
defined module Converters
defined class A

scala> val a = new A()

scala> a.foo[Int]("0")
<console>:12: error: could not find implicit value for parameter ct: ConverterTo[Int]
          a.foo[Int]("0")
                    ^
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`import Converters._` in `class A` does not cut it. You can remove it and the code will still compile. The moment the compiler needs to find in actual implicit is not in `class A`, where `foo` is just declared.

The compiler needs to find a `ConverterTo[Int]` in implicit scope at the moment you call `a.foo[Int](..)` that is in the REPL. So this is where the import needs to be.

Had `object Converters` and `trait ConverterTo` been named the same (so there would be a companion object) the import would not be needed.

Comment: Thank you. Now it is obvious I need the import, where I call `a.foo[Int]` :) I hope I finally got it.

Comment: As for the companion object: I am afraid I cannot use it. My problem is that I need two different implementations of `ConvertersTo` to use in two different classes `A1` and `A2` that define `foo` as in the question. I will probably post another question about it.