# Is it possible to write typeclass with different implementations?

Tags: scala, typeclass, implicit

This is a follow-up to my previous [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29388145/how-to-fix-this-typeclass-example)

Suppose I have a trait `ConverterTo` and *two* implementations:

```
trait ConverterTo[T] {
  def convert(s: String): Option[T]
}

object Converters1 {
  implicit val toInt: ConverterTo[Int] = ???
}

object Converters2 {
  implicit val toInt: ConverterTo[Int] = ???
}
```

I have also two classes `A1` and `A2`

```
class A1 {
  def foo[T](s: String)(implicit ct: ConverterTo[T]) = ct.convert(s) 
}

class A2 {
  def bar[T](s: String)(implicit ct: ConverterTo[T]) = ct.convert(s)
}
```

Now I would like any `foo[T]` call to use `Converters1` and any `bar[T]` call to use `Converters2` *without* importing `Converters1` and `Converters2` in the client code.

```
val a1 = new A1()
val a2 = new A2()
...
val i = a1.foo[Int]("0") // use Converters1 without importing it
...
val j = a2.bar[Int]("0") // use Converters2 without importing it
```

Can it be done in Scala ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Import `Converters` in the class.

```
class A1 {
 import Converters1._
 private def fooPrivate[T](s: String)(implicit ct: ConverterTo[T]) = ct.convert(s) 
 def fooShownToClient[T](s: String) = fooPrivate(s)
}
```

Then use the method, that is shown to client

```
val a1 = new A1()
a1.fooShownToClient[Int]("0")
```

Now the client is unaware of the convertors.

Comment: Um... what's the point of even having a fooPrivate here? If the implicit isn't externally visible/configurable you might just as well just call the method on the (now fixed) implementation directly.

Comment: @Cubic - I answered how he can call convertors method without importing it in client's code. There are many cases where OP might not want to show which convertors is going to be used. For example, convertor can be used to encrypt passwords using a specific algo. OP may not want to show that he uses which convertor to the client. As for using a implicit, a convertor and class A1 may contain many methods and OP mayn't want to pass Converters1.foo/Converters1.fooBar etc in each method. As you mentioned in your answer, it really depends on what OP wants

Comment: The hiding thing sounds like a pretty silly reason, considering that it can be trivially reverse engineered from the bytecode.

Comment: It was just an example. In any case, you should not tightly couple different parts of your code. Clients need not know anything more than what is absolutely necessary for them to function( That is know as OOPs data-hiding principle if I am not wrong) . As for reverse engineering, I have 1000+ files in my project. If I want to hide something from a client, I rather make sure the client work a little to figure things out  than to give the code on a silver platter. Security is all about creating hurdles.

Comment: Data hiding is one thing, but you got coupling exactly backwards; You're tightly coupling the implementation to a particular converter instance here. Anyway, this is getting off tangent.

Answer (score 1):

If you have a situation where you need more local control; You can just opt to pass the `implicit` parameters *explicitly*:

```
val i = a1.foo("0")(Converters1.toInt)
val j = a2.foo("0")(Converters2.toInt)
```

It really depends on what you want. If you want to select a particular implementation without polluting local scope, do it like this (or introduce a new scope). `mohit`'s solution works well if the classes *need* a particular implementation (although in that case, there's no real point in declaring this dependency as `implicit` anymore).